# alignof(char) == 1?

Tags: c++11

sizeof(char) is always 1 and it seems to me that the alignment requirement of a type can never be larger than its size. Quoting from the upcoming C++11 standard (3.11):

> An aligment is an implementation-deﬁned integer value representing
>   the number of bytes between successive addresses at which a given object can be allocated.

So if the alignment of a type were greater than its size, it would not be possible to create arrays without empty space between consecutive elements.

Is this interpretation correct and is thus alignof(char) == 1 always?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  What more are you seeking?

Comment: As I recall, `sizeof(char)==1` by definition.

Comment: @CommonSense: nothing more, was just trying to check if the reasoning is correct.

Comment: You might also consider the value of CHAR_BIT, which might help char get the correct alignment.

Comment: @Bo Persson: I was under the impression that sizeof and alignof speak in bytes, so how is CHAR_BIT useful in this context?

Comment: @bluescarni - It tells us the size of the byte. :-)  In C++ a byte is defined to be the same as a `char`, that's why sizeof(char) is always 1.

Comment: @Bo Persson: ok, but aren't alignment and size oblivious to the number of bits in a byte?

Comment: @bluescarni - If the "byte" contains 16 bits (or 32) it might have a different alignment than if it contains just 8 bits.

Comment: @Bo Persson: but the alignment of char will always be 1 byte, right? Whatever the bit width of a byte is?

Comment: @bluescami - Yes, but that's only because the language standard defines a byte so that this is true. It might still mean that the alignment is 32 bits.

Comment: @Raymond: OP was about `alignof`, not `sizeof`

Comment: @Raymond: No need to sorry, I permanently misread things ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.

You can infer from the **"compact" (no padding) layout of C++ arrays** that any object type such that an array of this type can be defined must have an alignment that is a divisor of its size.

In particular, the alignment of such a type of size 1 must be 1.

In particular, the alignment of `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` is 1.

OTOH, you cannot infer anything about the alignment of an abstract class with this argument.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the way C++11 defines pointer arithmetic and didn't see anything that would prevent a type's alignment from being larger than its size. The compiler would be responsible for making sure every element in the array was properly aligned (by inserting the right amount of padding) and for making sure that pointer arithmetic works properly. Basically, pointer arithmetic is not defined with reference to sizeof(*ptr) even though people usually talk about it as though it is.

> **n3290 § 5.7 p5:**
>
> When an expression that has integral type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the result has the type of the pointer operand. If the pointer operand points to an element of an array object, and the array is large enough, the result points to an element offset from the original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the resulting and original array elements equals the integral expression.

edit:

However, the `sizeof` operator is defined in terms of the offset between consecutive elements in an array, so `alignof(X)` can't be greater than `sizeof(X)` because that would mean an array of X contains objects at invalid alignments. At the same time, `sizeof(X)` doesn't necessarily represent the actual size of the object. E.g. an X member or base sub-object of another type may use less than `sizeof(X)` bytes to store, although I don't know of any implementation that actually uses that.

Comment: If such a requirement really was dropped by C++11, it would only mean that standard editing went wrong. Would not be the first time.

Comment: I believe you're thinking of the sizeof(char) == 1 requirement in C++. As far as I know alignof(char) has never been required to be 1. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Do you claim that `alignof(char) > 1` is deliberatly allowed in C/C++, or do you claim that both standard committees forgot to rule out this possibility?

Comment: It looks to me like the C++ standard deliberately allows types to have alignments larger than their size. So has the C++ standard ever required alignof(char) == 1? As far as I can tell it has not, so this is not a requirement that was 'dropped'.

Comment: What exactly makes you think that the standard **deliberately**, rather than accidentally, allows that?

Comment: What makes you think it's an accident? I think the C++ standards committee deliberately didn't add in this arbitrary restriction because they have a habit of not adding arbitrary restrictions that prevent platforms that aren't exactly the same as other platforms from being able to use standard C++. For example x64 has a 10-byte type with 16-byte alignment. If C++ included a restriction that the maximum alignment for a type was its size then a C++ programs using that type would receive a huge performance penalty.

Comment: But this restriction has always existed in C/C++. What is this type?

Comment: Can you cite your source for that please? C++ has always defined sizeof(char) == 1 but I'm not aware that there was ever such a restriction on alignof(char).

Comment: My source is: every one knows that. There cannot be a better source. When have you met an array with padding in C/C++?

Comment: "There cannot be a better source." @_@

Comment: N3242 is another source. 8.3.4 Arrays [dcl.array] "An object of array type contains a contiguously allocated non-empty set of N subobjects of type T." That was hard to find. (No it wasn't.)

Comment: Alright, that's a better source. Also 5.3.3/2 says "When applied to a class, the result is the number of bytes in an object of that class including any padding required for placing objects of that type in an array." which could be taken to mean that sizeof returns the 'size' of the object when it's in any array even though that might not be the size of the object in other contexts.

Comment: What do you mean by "_the object in other contexts_"? Do you mean that the object representation might change depending on the fact that the object is/isn't in an array?

Comment: Not really change, unless you count including padding or not as a change in representation. Any sub-objects would remain at the same positions whether the object were in an array or not, so in that sense the representation isn't changing at all. The only change would be that, outside of an array, the compiler could potentially allocate less than `sizeof` bytes to hold the object.

Comment: Actually, come to think of it the definition you quoted for arrays doesn't actually mean there can't be padding between objects. 'contiguously allocated' just means that the allocated space is contiguous, not that the array sub-objects are contiguous with each other. However the definition for `sizeof` is pretty explicit that it counts padding.

Comment: When used as a base class: a derived class can make good use of the base class tail padding (padding after the last member). In general, a complete object of type `T` will use exactly `sizeof(T)` contiguous bytes.